# <<END_SCRIPT while connecting to FTP via bash

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

I have never written a shell-script before and am trying to understand this piece of code:

```
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

What does the `<<END_SCRIPT` signify? And what is the quote call doing? Thanks in advance, again I am a super newb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<<` is [heredoc syntax](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) in bash

For the [`quote, put, quit`](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Protocols/ftp.php) is FTP command